# mysql general log destination file to table version 5.5

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, general-log

I have mysql server 5.5, I want to change default general file destinahtion (Which is /var/log/mysql/mysql.log) to table.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: yes I checked. I find that if I start mysql withh --log-output option. But I never know how to use this option.